# WPF DataGrid Slow Loading during render

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid with almost 8000 Rows. It's taking approx. 25 seconds to load. Any clues how do I improve its performance?

This Grid has 3 static `ButtonType` Columns and other columns are dynamic. I fetch data inside a list and assign it to the `ItemsSource` property of the DataGrid on CodeBehind.

Here is the XAML code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TransportApp.Views.CommonScreen.SideBar.DetailsGrid"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Margin="5,0,0,0" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Name="DisplayHeader" Grid.Row="0" Content="Information" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" />
            <DatePicker Name="dtGridFilterDate" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="4" SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"/>
            <mui:ModernButton Name="Cmd_Refresh" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" ToolTip="Click to Refresh View" IconData="{StaticResource RefreshIconData}" EllipseStrokeThickness="2" EllipseDiameter="26" IconHeight="15" IconWidth="15" Click="Cmd_Refresh_Click"/>
            <DockPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1">
                <Label FontWeight="Bold" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="lblFilter" Content="Filter" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Name="filterBox1"/>
            </DockPanel>
            <mui:ModernButton Name="cmdSearch" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" ToolTip="Click to Search" IconData="{StaticResource SearchData}" EllipseStrokeThickness="2" EllipseDiameter="26" IconHeight="11" IconWidth="11" Click="cmdSearch_Click"/>
        </Grid>

        <DataGrid Name="DG_Details" Grid.Row="1" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" 
                      CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                      SelectionMode="Single" EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                      VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                      AutoGeneratingColumn="DG_Details_AutoGeneratingColumn" 
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="dgEditColumn">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <mui:ModernButton Name="Cmd_Edit" Click="Cmd_Edit_Click" ToolTip="Edit" IconData="{StaticResource EditIconData}" EllipseStrokeThickness="2" EllipseDiameter="20" IconHeight="10" IconWidth="10"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="dgDeleteColumn">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <mui:ModernButton Name="Cmd_Delete" Click="Cmd_Delete_Click" ToolTip="Delete" IconData="{StaticResource DeleteIconData}" EllipseStrokeThickness="2" EllipseDiameter="20" IconHeight="10" IconWidth="10"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="dgPrintColumn" Visibility="Hidden">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <mui:ModernButton Name="Cmd_Print" Click="Cmd_Print_Click" ToolTip="Re-Print document" IconData="{StaticResource PrintIconData}" EllipseStrokeThickness="2" EllipseDiameter="20" IconHeight="10" IconWidth="10"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Data Loading Logic**

```
var customerList = (from c in context.Customers
                                            where c.IsDeleted == false
                                            select new
                                            {
                                                FirstName = c.FirstName,
                                                LastName = c.LastName,
                                                Phone = c.Phone,
                                                CustomerId = c.CustomerId
                                            }).ToList();

                            DG_Details.ItemsSource = customerList;
                            DG_Details.Items.Refresh();
```

A thing to note here is, DataGrid's performance is great after loading. No lag at all. I am using a Core i5 machine with 4 GB RAM and 512 MB graphics card.

Please let me know if any optimizations can be done in this code.

Comment: Don't use a DataGrid.  Use ListView / GridView.

Comment: @Blam: I could spot ListView in the ToolBox but no GridView

Comment: The problem might be the loading logic and not the datagrid, because the datagrid is using virtualisation. So why don't you show the loading logic instead of the xaml ?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: Updated the post :) I am using entity framework in my project.

Comment: @Blam: This ListView/GridView approach is not bad. Atleast its loading data in 1 sec. Just that I will have to modify lot many things :(

Comment: You have to add some debug traces in your code to see where this 25s is spent. Before ToList and after ToList print, the time, and also after Refresh. Then you are sure where the time is spent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataGrid does a lot of stuff but it also has a lot of overhead.

ListView / GridView is more work but is faster.

Comment: yeah this solution looks more elegant. I have increased records in my table to 55000 and its loading in approx 4 secs. That's a significant improvement.